# 'swipl_qid' ignored in Python application

Tags: python, swi-prolog

I develop python app which connect to Prolog via pyswip.
The following code is when I ask a question from prolog.

```
self.prolog = Prolog()
self.prolog.consult("Checker.pl")
self.prolog.query("playX")
```

This is the sample of my Prolog code

```
playX :-
      init(B),
      assert(min_to_move(x/_)),assert(max_to_move(o/_)),
      play(human, x, B).
```

When query ("playX"), there is a message

```
Exception AttributeError: 'swipl_qid' in <bound method _QueryWrapper.__del__ of <pyswip.prolog._QueryWrapper object at 0x0000000004620288>> ignored
```

What happen?

Ps. I use all 64 bit: Python 2.7, SWI-Prolog, pyswip, Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not an error, rather a strange message if you don't iterate or cast the result of your query. If you instead of:

```
self.prolog.query("playX")
```

you write:

```
result = list(self.prolog.query("playX"))
```

then variable "result" will contain the set of solutions to your query (in your case you will get the empty list []) and the exception will not be raised.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the query like you do in Python.

For x in  self.prolog.query("playX"):
    Print x